# Eclipse not showing Axis2 Preferences Under Window>>Preferences>>Web Services

Tags: eclipse, web, apache-axis

I am trying to develop web services. I have successfully Installed, Tomcat 7 and the axis2.war under the Tomcats webapps folder. I am using Eclipse Indigo. One of the Instructions includes setting the parameters under the Web services>>Axis2 Preferences and also the Axis Emiter is missing but I do not have that option. How can I include those options under my Web Services.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse for Java EE Developers? To me this sounds as you have the Standard Version. Webservices are in Java EE.

Comment: I am using Java EE. I have tried to find solutions but I still cant see them anywhere

Comment: To point out: i mean Eclipse for Java EE, apart from the JDK EE from Oracle. What does your "About Eclipse" menu selection say? Or could you try Eclipse Kepler, or is there a specific reason you use Indigo?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I used Eclipse standard while Axis2 is in Eclipse for Java EE developers.

Answer (score -1):

I changed projects Dynamic web module 2.5 to 3.1 then Axis 2 Preferences became visible.
Project ->Properties -> Project Facets -> Dynamic Web Module